# Привести формулу в "красивый" вид c#

Tags: c#, math

есть допустим уравнение `2x^2+3x+6=0` или `lim_n->10 (x)` нужно отобразить это "красиво" чтоб без `^`, а `2` была сверху и т.п. Стандартными средствами это вряд ли можно реализовать, есть ли какой компонент для этого?

Comment: Winforms или WPF?

Comment: Компоненты Tex'а посмотрите. к примеру pdflatex

Comment: Вот по теме: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8899204/276994

Comment: желательно Winforms . Спасибо всем за ссылки, буду смотреть

Comment: а RitchTextBox не устраивает?

Comment: а как туда записать в красивой форме ? допустим в текстбоксе у меня есть 2x^2+3x+6=0, как в ричедите записать красивую форму ?

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет `WPF-Math` : https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math

Comment: хотя пока библиотека только для `WPF`

Comment: +, тоже вчера на нее наткнулся, спасибо